# Should I use ">=" (greater than or equal to) for the node or npm versions in package.json engines field for a node package?

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json, semantic-versioning

The package is developed locally using the [LTS](https://nodejs.org) version of `node` (currently `12.18.2`). Under [engines](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#engines), I have `node` set to `12.18.2`, but I've noticed that using `>=` is common (see [yarn](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/blob/master/package.json#L107)) - how can I decide if I should "relax" my node version? I'm also considering `~12.18.2`.

**Benefit**: Package consumers won't get a warning if they're using a version of `node` that still works with the package, despite being higher than the version specified in the `package.json`.

**Potential Risk**: Is the concern that a future version of `node` will have a breaking change or deprecation that will affect my package?

---

I have the same question about using `>=` for the `npm` version.

Comment: Great question - pkg authors specify [semver ranges](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver#ranges) for node engine too. For instance **1)** Running `npm show eslint@7.4.0 engines.node` returns `^10.12.0 || >=12.0.0` **2)** `npm show npm@6.14.6 engines.node` returns `>=6.2.0 || 8 || >=9.3.0`. Given that SemVer is essentially a contract for communicating to users how impactful a change is, and whether things will/wont work... Specifying `~12.18.2` seems realistic to me, (until it's proven otherwise). Specifying `>=` is maybe too unrealistic as you're communicating to users this pkg will work ...

Comment: ... with all future releases of nodejs. If you don't know yourself whether your pkg works with future node version X, (how can you possibly know!), then a user getting a warning is not such a bad thing - contractually you're warning them it's not proven whether it will/wont work.

Comment: Thank you @RobC! So why do you think major packages use >=?

Comment: I've no idea why they use `>=` - just because they do doesn't mean they're right. It seems unjustifiable to me, perhaps they haven't given it much thought (or I'm misunderstanding something). Actually in your scenario specifying `^12.18.2` is more appropriate because if node.js complies with [semver rules](https://semver.org/#semantic-versioning-specification-semver) then in theory (and hopefully in practice) no release til `>=13` could cause an incompatible API change that _may_ affect your package. Btw. npm's node engines as `>=6.2.0 || 8 || >=9.3.0` seem wrong too, why not just `>=6.2.0`.

Comment: You're right that npm's node engines make no sense - https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver is a cool way to verify this (they have another confusing example there too...)! Agree with using `^` in my scenario - good catch.

Comment: @RobC I've been thinking about this because I'm writing a script to automatically load a compatible version of node based on the package.json. I think using `>=` is fine for engines.node in the majority of cases because it allows new major versions of node to be used by consuming applications which is normally what you want. As for the specific case of npm requiring >=9.3.0 as well as >=6.2.0 or any version 8, I'm not sure about needing the 8, but it does enforce versions of 9 greater than 9.3.0. The `>=6.2.0` should probably be `^6.2.0`, but it still works.